# RSA Q and P too big

Tags: c++, rsa

I have a problem with my RSA code. It is working for small p and q for example if i enter p = 11, q = 3, e = 3,n = 33 and d = 7.

But if i give a bigger value for them, it´s not working anymore. I been debugging my code and saw that the problem occurs in the decryptMsg method. I think that some value might be too big. But wolfram alpha for example can handle this calculation. Below you can see my code for the encrypt and decrypt method.

```
long double encryptMsg(int n, int e, long double message) {
    // Encryption c = (msg ^ e) % n 
    long double c = pow(message, (long double)e);
    long double k = fmod(c, (long double)n);
    cout << "encrypted message : " << k << endl;
    return k;
}

void decryptMsg(int n, int d, long double message) {
    // Decryption m = (c ^ d) % n 
    long double k = pow(message, (long double)d);
    long double erg = fmod(k, (long double)n);
    cout << erg << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using floating point, pow is likely to go off.

Comment: because i get the error the Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type if i use modulo %

Comment: You should use arbitrary precision integers for that. RSA by definition deals with big numbers. Check the GMP library.

Comment: Does that mean that i can´t handle this overflow the only thing i can do is using GMP library ?

Comment: Dear lord... are you seriously using floating point for cryptography? You should be using some multiprecision library. Please learn how to use openssl or some other cryptography library. Openssl has "bignum" in it to deal with huge numbers. Don't even think of using native types. And btw, don't roll your own crypto. That's rule no. 1.